# Object Test Bench flashes quickly whenever I run (F5) in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio

Maybe a silly question but one day I did something accidentally in VS2008 and ever since then, whenever I hit F5, just before my app appears, I see a quick flash of a small window labeled "Object Test Bench". ie, it appears and very quickly disappears.

I've read about Object Test Bench and (since this happened) had a quick play with it in View / Other Windows but I haven't been able to stop that quick flash.

It's not really a problem, VS seems to work fine but I'm always uncomfortable about something happening that I don't understand and didn't happen before.

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same problem.  I once had JetBrain's Resharper 4.5 installed.  I uninstalled it after my trial expired, and I think that's when I noticed the Object Test Bench popping up when I debug.

Did either/both of you have Resharper or any other Visual Studio add-on installed/uninstalled before this problem?

**UPDATE**

Try resetting the Visual Studio settings.  [How to: Reset Your Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075(VS.80).aspx)

After resetting, the object test bench popup went away.

Comment: No, I haven't used any add-ins at all.

Comment: I reset my Visual Studio settings and the object test bench popup went away.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you would rather not lose all of your settings:

- export your current settings
- reset all settings
- import selected settings from your exported back-up settings.  Keep everything else, but de-select 'window layouts'