# Visual studio 2005 "Object Test Bench" popup when debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

When debugging a project in Visual Studio 2005, I have recently noticed a brief appearance of the "Object Test Bench" window. This window appears and then disappears after less than a second and does not look like the normal "Object Test Bench" window one sees when not debugging, as it looks like this:

[alt text http://www.beok.co.il/images/ObjectTestBench.jpg](http://www.beok.co.il/images/ObjectTestBench.jpg)

I would like to stop this window appearing and have tried the following:

- Closing all Object Bench Test windows when not debugging
- Resetting Visual Studio to default settings (devenv /ResetSettings)

Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have a custom control library as part of your solution by any chance?

Comment: No custom control is being developed, have tried this with a standard console exe solution

Answer (score 0):

Migrated? Hmm no code in this question. Anyway is the Object Test Bench perhaps open, but docked, so it pops up when the IDE state changes?

More info on the [OTB on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3775d98(VS.80).aspx) here :)

*Edit: Here is what my VS 2005 OTB looks like.*

[alt text http://i.imagehost.org/0989/otb.gif](http://i.imagehost.org/0989/otb.gif)

Comment: It is not open in anyway. It just appears for a split second when debugging is started.

Comment: when I open Object Test Bench via View -> Other Windows it looks a bit different (and not window visual styles either). What VS addins do you have installed? (Tools -> Addin manager)

Comment: While testing, I removed all addins. With a completely clean VS2005 this still appears.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which version of Windows are you using? Perhaps there is a known IDE bug involved? -- ps happy new years!

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem. I once had JetBrain's Resharper 4.5 installed. I uninstalled it after my trial expired, and I think that's when I noticed the Object Test Bench popping up when I debug.

Did either/both of you have Resharper or any other Visual Studio add-on installed/uninstalled before this problem?

[Related link on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342093/object-test-bench-flashes-quickly-whenever-i-run-f5-in-vs2008)

Comment: Yes, I had resharper installed (I believe v5) and since the removal this occurred.

Comment: I reset my Visual Studio settings and the object test bench popup went away.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had what may be a similar problem: not just the Oject Test Bench, but also Breakpoint, Call Stack, and other windows popped up all over whenever I ran in Debug mode. It started during a project with a single page containing several (probably incompatible) jQuery scripts.

What worked for me was to click on Window -> "Auto Hide All", then again on Window -> "Reset Window Layout". That seemed to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to on Window -> "Auto Hide All", after go on Window -> "Reset Window Layout". That will resolve the problem it.